# Run multiple emulators using Jenkins Android Emulator Plugin

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, android-emulator-plugin

I want to test an app on multiple emulators with different screen sizes. I prefer to have just one build plan instead of a build plan for every emulator configuration.

Is is possible to run e.g. 3 emulators with different configurations using Android Emulator Plugin for Jenkins?

Is there some other plugin to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [Matrix plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Matrix+Project+Plugin) is a good solution for this, as discussed on the [wiki page](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Android+Emulator+Plugin#AndroidEmulatorPlugin-Multiconfiguration%28matrix%29job) for the emulator plugin.

This lets you have a single Jenkins job, where you define the various configuration combinations you want — Jenkins will then run a series of sub-jobs to fulfil each combination, in turn creating the desired Android emulator config.

Comment: Does it also collects all reports and merge them as the build was run as a single job with multiple emulators? What I want is a single report with test failures. I can't find this info on their page.

Comment: Yes, it does that.